# Celery can not find periodic tasks after importing libraries

Tags: python, django, celery

I am trying to create periodic task with celery, which every day download some file from the web. But I run into a problem when I try to import libraries in file where I create the task. I get an error `Received unregistered task of type 'download_data_nist.tasks.download_data'`. If I delete the imports, 
the task is executed without errors.

I have configured Celery in settings.py:

```
from celery.schedules import crontab

CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'amqp://localhost'
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'CET'
CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'task-number-one': {
        'task': 'download_data_nist.tasks.download_data',
        'schedule': crontab(minute='*/1'),
    },
}
```

I have created celery.py in root folder of my app:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'AplikacijaZaPregledRanljivosti.settings')

app = Celery('AplikacijaZaPregledRanljivosti')

# Using a string here means the worker don't have to serialize
# the configuration object to child processes.
# - namespace='CELERY' means all celery-related configuration keys
#   should have a `CELERY_` prefix.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

# Load task modules from all registered Django app configs.
app.autodiscover_tasks()


@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

I add this code to **init**.py in root folder:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

# This will make sure the app is always imported when
# Django starts so that shared_task will use this app.
from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ['celery_app']
```

When I get an error my tasks.py looks like this:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

from celery import task
import json
import re
import requests
import zipfile
from django.conf import settings

@task()
def download_data():
    return "Data downloaded"
```

When task is executed tasks.py looks like this:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

from celery import task

@task()
def download_data():
    return "Data downloaded"
```

How can I import the libraries without getting error?

Comment: Do you really need the `from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals` line?

Comment: I copied this line from the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure about two things when you get `unregistered task` error from celery worker:

1. Inform celery about your app modules in `settings.py`. This will also help you to understand what dependency error you might be encountering:

```py
# settings.py
CELERY_IMPORTS = (
    'your_app_name.tasks'
)
```

2. Make sure you have satisfied all of your dependency libraries in your virtual environment or etc. In this case, you need to make sure you've installed `requests` etc.

Comment: I forget to install requests. Thank you for your help.